# How do you read the files in a sub-directory in python?

Tags: python

I am working on a python program, and the first step is to open and read the files that I have. But they are contained in a sub-directory. I managed to list them with the following code:

```py
import os
from glob import glob

PATH = "databases/"
EXT = "*.csv"
all_csv_files = [file
                 for path, subdir, files in os.walk(PATH)
                 for file in glob(os.path.join(path, EXT))]
print(all_csv_files)
```

But I can't figure out how to read them, as in with reader or dictreader. If you know, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to loop over `all_csv_files` and the `open()` function to open them one-by-one within the loop.

Comment: Not really because I'm a beginner to python and don't understand the code in that question.

Comment: @Lostincode that doesn't mean it doesn't answer your question. If you will keep avoiding stuff that you don't understand, how will you learn and get better? Also don't look at the code in the question, but the accepted answer. The code there is almost simpler than yours...

Comment: Ok, It's just that I'm new to python and sites like SO, so I sometimes don't look at the right thing to get my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to get the content of those files:

```
import os
from glob import glob

PATH = "databases/"
EXT = "*.csv"
all_csv_file_content = [open(os.path.join(path, file), "r").read()
                 for path, subdir, files in os.walk(PATH)
                 for file in glob(os.path.join(path, EXT))]
print(all_csv_file_content)
```

- `os.path.join(path, file)` this will return the full path to specific files.
- With `open` and `read` we get the content of one file as a big
  string.

Comment: ok, thanks. Also, thanks for the explanation at the end of your code, I really appreciate it. I don't like blindly copy-pasting code.